# No static method ThreadLocal.withInitial() : commons-io dependency

Tags: java, android, apache-commons, apache-commons-io

I am using commons-io dependency in my Android Studio project.

`implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.11.0'`

But I am seeing these weird crashes in Crashlytics. These crashes are showing up on Android 7 and below.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method withInitial(Ljava/util/function/Supplier;)Ljava/lang/ThreadLocal; in class Ljava/lang/ThreadLocal; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.lang.ThreadLocal' appears in /system/framework/core-oj.jar)
   at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.<clinit>(IOUtils.java:183)
   at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.closeQuietly(IOUtils.java:534)
```

I have also included Java 8 compatibility in my project.

```
android {

...
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can downgrade the library to version '2.8.0' as after this version they are using ThreadLocal which is not supported in android 7.

So just use this in app/build.gradle

```
 implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.8.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Internally commons-io is using ThreadLocal#withInitial API which is not part of [desugared library](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table), hence the method is not available on API levels lower than 26 (Android OREO)

To read more about this you can read the discussion of [this thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160484830) on google issue tracker.

**Solution:**

We can use the previous versions of commons-io which are not using the ThreadLocal API. So i ended up using `implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'`